# Creating new ldap entry with go

Tags: go

I'm creating an application that needs to add a new ldap entry in openDJ.

I can think of two possible solutions currently:

- Use template to create ldif file, then `File.Write` to place it in a directory.  Next, have a cronjob check every 2-5 minutes if there is a new file in the directory. If there is, run `ldapmodify` to add new entry
- The second option is to also create a file in a directory, but then to run `ldapmodify` using `exec.Command()`

I'm leaning towards the second method as it is simpler, but I'm not sure if it is less secure.  I've never been a fan of executing shell commands inside a program.  And I don't know if there is a performance hit because of it.

I'm open to any suggestions, but those are the two methods I came up with.

Comment: Why not use a thought through library? https://github.com/mmitton/ldap or https://github.com/tonnerre/go-ldap

Comment: The main reason is those libraries don't have support for adding/modifying records yet.

Comment: It's open source. Add that functionality yourself and commit it to them, or fork the repo :) Wondrous world of open-source <3

Answer (score 0):

Use this [LDAP library](https://github.com/johnweldon/ldap), or any of the forks. It does support modify and add. Alternatively you can interface the [API provided by openLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=(3)&sektion=&apropos=1&manpath=OpenLDAP%202.4-Release&title=Section%20).